# How to use readFileToByteArray with image from gallery

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to implement in my app the haystack.ai API. I read the documentation. I need help to change something in my code.

In the example code in the documentation, you provide the path of your image. I need to let the user choose a picture from the gallery(I know how to do that) and then convert the picture into an array of byte.
That's what I tried:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rate);

    backBtn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
    image = findViewById(R.id.imageRated);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        imageUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("uri"));
        image.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    try {
        getScore();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getScore() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://api.haystack.ai/api/image/analyze?output=json&apikey=myapikey");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    byte[] imageData = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(imageUri.toString()));
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    os.write(imageData);
    os.close();

    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream responseBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while (true) {
        int n = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (n <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        responseBuffer.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }

    String response = responseBuffer.toString("UTF-8");
    Log.v("Score", response);
}
```

}

The logcat says :

`RateActivity.getScore(Unknown Source:12) at line 62` --->

```
byte[] imageData = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(imageUri.toString()));
```

I also tried:

```
byte[] imageData = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(imageUri.getPath()));
```

The original code in the documentation is:

```
byte[] imageData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("testImage4.jpg"));
```

I need to convert the selected picture for the imageData array.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> From your question it seems that you want to convert image URI to
>   byteArray.

If it is the case you can try the code below.

```
public void convertUriToByteArray(String uri)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fIn = null;
        try {
            fIn = new FileInputStream(new File(uri));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        try {
            while (-1 != (n = fIn.read(buf)))
                bArray.write(buf, 0, n);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] bytes = bArray.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: No, maybe I expressed myself badly. I need to convert the image from the URI to a byteArray. In the documentation they pass the path of the image. On Android, the path is the URI. And I need to use that path to convert the selected image